# How to securely connect to Azure Cache for Redis from Laravel

Tags: laravel, azure, redis, config

Azure Cache for Redis provides secure port for connecting over TLS.

How to setup Laravel Redis config for connecting securely?

Answer (score 1):

Use 6380 port and add `tls://` to host.

`.env` file:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=tls://RESOURCE_NAME.redis.cache.windows.net
REDIS_PASSWORD=password
REDIS_PORT=6380
```